# Perl create graph after taking values by STDIN

Tags: perl

I have a code in PERL which works perfectly when i take the values directly

```
$graph = {
  'A' => {'B' => 1, 'C' => 5},
  'B' => {'C' => 4, 'D' => 2},
  'C' => {'A' => 1, 'B' => 3},
  'D' => {'C' => 2, 'B' => 3}
};
```

But my input is in this format

```
A B 1
A C 5
B C 4
B D 2
C A 1
C B 3
D C 2
D B 3
```

How to change this input to graph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check [`HoH`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#Generation-of-a-HASH-OF-HASHES) generation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $graph = {};
while (<DATA>) {
  my ($k1, $k2, $val) = split;
  $graph->{ $k1 }{ $k2 } = $val;
}

__DATA__
A B 1
A C 5
B C 4
B D 2
C A 1
C B 3
D C 2
D B 3
```